# Как проверить порт у 127.0.0.1 через nginx в debian

Tags: linux, nginx, debian

Установил Nginx в debian через терминал. Надо проверить [http://127.0.0.1:[порт](http://127.0.0.1:%5B%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%82) куда поставилось по дефолту]

Проблема в том, когда пробую открыть http://127.0.0.1 через браузер, то он открывается.
Когда проверяю при помощи утилиты nmap, то пишет что этот адрес использует порт 80, но вот, когда использую netstat, то его нет в списке.

[image: netstat]

[image: nmap]

Знаю как можно добавить в ручную, но надо именно без лишних действий все это сделать.

Comment: Что значит «нет в списке», если вот прям на вашем скриншоте `0.0.0.0:80` прекрасно виден?

Comment: Если не ошибаюсь, то 0.0.0.0 означает, что он прослушивает все адреса IPv4, назначенные машине.

По крайне мере, так написано на англоязычном стаке https://superuser.com/questions/240105/netstat-a-command-difference-between-0-0-0-0-and-127-0-0-1

Comment: И 127.0.0.1 входит в эти «все адреса IPv4», всё верно

Comment: Есть ли способ, чтобы он вывел именно 127.0.0.1 

Я в интернете встречал такое, даже в той же ссылке у него показывает 127.0.0.1 и 0.0.0.0 отдельно дург от друга [https://superuser.com/questions/240105/netstat-a-command-difference-between-0-0-0-0-and-127-0-0-1]

Comment: Значит измените параметр listen в настройках nginx так, чтобы он слушал только 127.0.0.1. Но тогда, разумеется, никто извне не сможет подключиться к этому nginx

Comment: Спасибо, что помогли сэкономить время